# Flutter/Firestore - FutureBuilder causing NoSuchMethodError even after null checks

Tags: null, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter, nosuchmethoderror

I am trying to retrieve values from my Firestore database. I am using the FutureBuilder to build the widget that requires those values. The following codes are causing me errors:

```
FutureBuilder(
          future: Firestore.instance.collection('Users').document(_uid).get(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              if (snapshot.data != null) {
                print(snapshot.data["firstName"]); //error occurs here
              }
            } else {
              return new CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
          },
        )
```

The error is as follows:
        `NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
        Receiver: null
        Tried calling: []("firstName")`
Somehow, the document snapshot is still a null even after the null checks. Any ideas why? Even stranger: The code actually works when I hot reload. However, when I switch to this page in my app, this error pops out again. I have tried implementing a try-catch that returns a CircularProgressIndicator, however, the page just stays as a permanent CircularProgressIndicator when it hits the error. I think it might be solved if I could catch the error and reload the FutureBuilder. Either that or if I could solve the mystery of why the document snapshot is null even after the null checks.

*Edit: I found the problem: The _uid is causing me issues. When I hardcode a _uid in, it works well. As such, the problem lies with how I get my _uid at the start of the page. This is how I get my _uid, written just above my build codes:

```
void initState()  {
    super.initState();
    // Listen for our auth event (on reload or start)
    // Assign variables once logged in
    _auth.onAuthStateChanged
        .firstWhere((user) => user != null)
        .then((user) {
      _uid = user.uid;
      print (_uid);
    });
  }
```

Comment: `Tried calling: []("firstName")` looks different than your above code. Are you sure it's not caused by other code? Try executing `flutter clean` in a terminal in your project directory, perhaps some code changes are not reflected in the running app.

Comment: I ran flutter clean but the problem still persists. I have printed statements around the code, so I am sure that the "print(snapshot.data["firstName"])" is the one giving me issues.